# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, html, django

I am not able to save the changes in the database. And how to call a view using links.
I want to edit the data onclick of edit link, save data onclick of save link and update data onclick of move link. Kindly help.

Here is my views.py:

```
def answer(request):
    info2 = Trans.objects.filter(transtype=8)
    sid = 0
if request.GET:
  sid = request.GET.get('sid')
bookdata = { "details" : info2, 'sid':int(sid) }
info2.save()
resp =  render_to_response("account/answer.html", bookdata, context_instance=Context(request))
return resp
```

HTML Template:

```
{% load i18n %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" style="width:800px">
<form action=" " method="POST">
<input type=hidden value= {{ s.id }} name ='sid'>
<tr>
{% for s in details %} 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>   
       {{ s.script }}
  {% if s.id == sid %}
        <input name="script" value="{{ s.script }}" />

  {% endif %}
</td>

<td> <a href="/accounts/answer/?sid={{ s.id }}" name="edit">Edit</a> </td>
<td> <a href="/accounts/answer/?sid={{ s.id }}" name="save">Save</a> </td>
<td> <a href="/accounts/answer/?sid={{ s.id }}" name="move">Move</a> </td>
{% endfor %} 

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Models.py file:

```
class Trans(models.Model):
    transtype = models.ForeignKey(TransType)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    script = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    movestatus= models.SmallIntegerField(default = 0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) 
    class Meta:
          unique_together = (("transtype", "script"),)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.transtype)
```

Comment: You need to step back and see what you are trying to do and how to do that. On specific question `info2` is queryset not an object, so you cannot save it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the update() method since you're dealing with a queryset (multiple objects)

Read examples here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Answer (score -2):

You should replace this line `info2 = Trans.objects.filter(transtype=8)` with this line `info2=Trans.objects.get(transtype=8)`